Javascript and Spring communication, how to include an Authorization Header on redirect?
I'm doing some practice with a SpringBoot Project which includes a JWT Filter.
Right now the filter is extracting the token from the Authorization Header, everything is working correctly as it should, tested it with Postman.
The problem is that im trying to make a web page, server side rendered using Thymeleaf and i don't know how to keep the token inside my requests.
Right now I'm testing a login page, the endpoint receives credentials and returns the appropriate Response, including JWT inside the body, my Javascript code (it's embedded inside the html) is supposed to receive the token, save it inside the local storage and include it inside the request when redirecting.
When hardcoding the token inside the Header using some browser extension it works how it should, but without it, it doesn't work.
I've made some research and I've understood that what I'm doing is wrong since axios it's used with SPAs and it's not able to redirect to another page and modify the Header.
Is there any way i can perform what i want?
Sorry if it looks stupid but I don't actually have any front-end knowledge, it was just something i wanted to add to my Spring project.
This is what i tried without success.
`async function handleSuccess(response) {
    const token = response.data.jwt;
    const redirect = response.data.url;
    localStorage.setItem('jwt', token);
    const headers = {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    };

    try {
        // Await the axios.get request
        const result = await axios.get(redirect, { headers: headers });
        console.log('Headers:', headers);
        window.location.href = redirect;
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors during redirection
        alert('errore');
        console.error('Error during redirection:', error);
    }
} `


When using traditional server-render based web development, the session-id inside cookie will be sent automatically by browser (that is, bind session id with principal/user on login), you can also take the jwt token to url query parameter. Server side will extract session-id/url-query-parameter from request to identify who you are.

What if i keep my logic but using Cookies instead? i see that i can store Jwt in cookies and retrieve it with CookieValue
